# Number of subspaces, that doesn't intersect given subspace.

Tags: vector-spaces

How many different subspaces size m in field $\mathbb {F}_{q}^{n}$ haven't  intersection with given subspace size l.
It's clear, that i need choose first vector for subspace's basis from $q^n - q^l - 1$ vectors. Second from $q^n - q^l - 1 - q$ and so.
But how consider, that different bases can give same vector subspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to count the subspaces $W$ of dimension $m$ which have $W\cap U=0$ for some fixed space $U$ of dimension $l$. Strategy is to count ordered linearly independent sets of size $m$ which span a space meeting $U$ trivially; then divide my the  number of ways such a set gives the same space $W$.

First bit:

Choose any $w_1\in V\setminus U$ : $q^n-q^l$ ways.

Choose any $w_2\in V\setminus \text{span} \{U, w_1\}$: $q^n-q^{l+1}$ ways

Choose any $w_3\in V\setminus \text{span} \{U, w_1, w_2\}$: $q^n-q^{l+2}$ ways

etc..

This gives $\prod_{j=0}^{m-1} (q^n-q^{l+j})$ ways to pick the ordered basis of $W$.

Now for the second part: what is essentially the same argument yields that there are 
$\prod_{j=0}^{m-1} (q^m-q^j)$ bases for a given $W$.

The quotient of these numbers is the answer.

Comment: Good. These sums are fun!